# multiple like on same column DB2

Tags: sql, syntax, db2

I am trying to query something like

```
select emp_id from dept.employee where
  firstname like '%sam%' or 
  firstname like '%SAM%' or
  firstname like '%will%' or
  firstname like '%WILL%'
```

Is it possible to put it in regex something like

```
select emp_id from dept.employee where
  firstname like '%sam|SAM|will|WILL%'
```

or

```
select emp_id from dept.employee where
  upper(firstname) like '%sam%' or
  upper(firstname) like '%will%'
```

I am using DB2 UDB9.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no immediate Regex function available in DB2. But it is possible to have an external user-defined function (calling either an external CLI, .NET or Java function) that implements regular expressions. Here's a ready-to-use example by IBM:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

Answer (score 1):

That's either a bad example or a bad database design :-).

You should probably not be storing first (or any) names in any way that will require you to use `LIKE`. You need to keep in mind that tables are almost *always* read far more often than written, and design accordingly.

That means you want the cost to be on insertion or update, not on selecting. Per-row functions such as `upper(name)` never scale well to proper enterprise-class databases.

In my opinion, you should have, for DB2, the following:

- an insert/update trigger that will remove leading and trailing spaces from the first (and last) name.
- a generated column that will uppercase the names (this uses more storage but that's usually better than wasting time). I'm not sure if UDB9 has generated columns (DB2/z has) but you can do this in the same insert/update trigger. Basically it's an extra column that's always set to the uppercase version of another field.
- an index on the generated column, not the original column.

That way, your selects will scream along with queries like (big and ugly, but efficient):

```
select * from tbl
where generatedname = 'SAM'
or    generatedname = 'SAMUEL'
or    generatedname = 'SAMANTHA'
or    generatedname = 'WILL'
or    generatedname = 'WILLIAM'
or    generatedname = 'WILLOMENA'
```

or (less big and ugly, just as efficient, and closer to the original query in intent):

```
select * from tbl
where generatedname like 'SAM%'
or    generatedname like 'WILL%'
```

using the full power of the query optimizer (DB2, and other DBMS' I would think, can still optimize 'XX%' easily if the field is indexed).

I'm not a big fan of using `LIKE` for any decent sized tables although sometimes there's not much choice. I can't think of any viable situation in which you'd want to look for `"%SAM%"` and  doing so results in an inability to use the optimizer to its fullest extent.

Comment: that was a bad example this is for a more less queried field more of description like field for a record.